# How to create a trigger that adds a new row to another table and a reference to the new row added to present table?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have this relation (A):

```
ID | B_ID
```

This relation (B):

```
ID | FOO
```

I want to add a trigger to `A` which will, on insertion of a new row into `A` (with `B_ID` always set as `NULL`), add a row in `B` with `FOO` set as `NULL` and set the `B_ID` attribute in the new row of `A` to reference the newly added `B` row.

Example:

Right after insertion into

`A`:

```
1 | NULL
```

After trigger action:

`A`:

```
1 | 555
```

`B`:

```
555 | NULL
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like the following:

```sql
/* Trigger structure for table `a` */

DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_a_bi` BEFORE INSERT ON `a`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `b` (`foo`) VALUES (NULL);
    SET NEW.`b_id` := LAST_INSERT_ID();
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Here a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/789e0c/1).